# JS object and number addition

Tags: javascript, implicit-conversion

```
{} + 5 === 5
5 + {} === '5[object Object]'
```

How is the first expression `{} + 5 === 5` calculated?

The second expression `5 + {} === '5[object Object]'` is expected result.

===== Edit ====

```
({}) + 5 === '[object Object]5'
```

Which might be to say: `{}` in first expression was ignored as the question comment says.

Comment: This is surely a dupe, but I don't think it has anything to do with JSFuck

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman that does not at all explain that the first "object" is interpreted as an empty code block

Comment: @CertainPerformance the empty code block is ignored, so it's a unary plus; that's why the result is just `5`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think I found some better ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{}` at the beginning of a line is considered a code block rather than an object literal. Thus `{} + 5` is not considered a binary addition between two values and evaluates to `+5`, unary + operator applied to 5.

When `{}` is placed inside round brackets it turns into object literal and the entire expression evaluates to `'[object Object]5'`

More details on this gotcha can be found [here](http://2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the following snippet, both expressions are converted to strings, so you get the following results, which is expected:

```
[object Object]5
5[object Object]
```

The reason this is happening is because `+` can't be addition between numbers since `{}` can't be cast to a number. Instead `+` is considered string concatenation here and both operands get converted to strings.

```js
console.log({} + 5 === '[object Object]5')
console.log(5 + {} === '5[object Object]')
```